# Object.freeze doesn't freeze objects in array

Tags: javascript, object

How come when I run :

```
var test = {
    'test': 5
};

Object.freeze(test);

// Will throw error
test.test = 3;
```

I'll get an error (as expected) but if I do this

```
var nestedTest = [
    {'test': 5},
    {'test': 6},
    {'test': 7},
    {'test': 8}
];

// Freeze all the objects in the array
for (var i = 0; nestedTest.length > i; i++) {
    Object.freeze(i);
};

// Will overwrite
test[0].test = 3;
```

I can reassign the values of those objects.

My thought would have been that the objects don't care that they're in an array.

Can someone clarify what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're freezing the index `i` instead of the object with the this index, your logic should be :

```
Object.freeze(nestedTest[i]);
```

Instead of :

```
Object.freeze(i);
```

Inside the `for` loop, full code :

```
// Freeze all the objects in the array
for (var i = 0; nestedTest.length > i; i++) {
    Object.freeze(nestedTest[i]);
};
```

**NOTE :** There's also a little typo in the last line, should be :

```
nestedTest[0].test = 3;
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var nestedTest = [
    {'test': 5},
    {'test': 6},
    {'test': 7},
    {'test': 8}
];

// Freeze all the objects in the array
for (var i = 0; nestedTest.length > i; i++) {
    Object.freeze(nestedTest[i]);
};

// Trying to overwrite
nestedTest[0].test = 3;

//Not overwriten
console.log(nestedTest[0]);
```

Comment: Just saw that when I went back and checked my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Object.freeze(i);` should be `Object.freeze(nestedTest[i]);` and `test[0].test = 3;` should be `nestedTest[0].test = 3;`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to make your syntax more concise by utilizing Javascript's functional features. Like, utilizing `.map` for Iterateable data structure. You don't need to use scope-leaky and error-prone `for` loop in this case.

The concise way would be:

```
var nestedTest = [
    {'test': 5},
    {'test': 6},
    {'test': 7},
    {'test': 8}
].map(item => Object.freeze(item));
```

Or even:

```
var nestedTest = [
    {'test': 5},
    {'test': 6},
    {'test': 7},
    {'test': 8}
].map(freezeArrayItem);

const freezeArrayItem = (item) => Object.freeze(item);
```